# Simple Bash script; Only works sometimes?

Tags: shell-script

In one of my bash-scripts where I use a file to write the current system time, I noticed that the correct time only gets written to the file every second time the script runs.

I did a second script to test it, and it shows the same behavior.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(date +"%F_%H:%M:%S")
wtimestamp="/home/pazau/logfiles/overviewer-timestamp"
timestamp=$(<$wtimestamp)

echo $NOW > $wtimestamp

echo $timestamp
```

The system is Ubuntu 14.04 x64, and a Raspberry Pi model B with raspbian. The behavior is the same on both systems.

Anything i'm missing?

Comment: For me it seems to work correctly. Maybe you expect to see the script output `$NOW` instead of the previous contents of the file: `$timestamp`.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct time only gets written to the file every second time"? The other times the file is not written? Or the other times an incorrect time is written?

Comment: @agold Nope, I was my intention to show the content from the file, to ensure that the time was correct written.

Comment: @techraf As far as I could see, the timestamp in the file was incorrect. As it turns out, the error happened because of wrong ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time stored is already correct, you just need to reorder the instructions to get what you expect:

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(date +"%F_%H:%M:%S")
wtimestamp="/home/pazau/logfiles/overviewer-timestamp"
echo $NOW > $wtimestamp
timestamp=$(<$wtimestamp)
echo $timestamp
```